# python - capturing stderr of subprocesses with their shell stdout alive

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stderr

Here are things I'm trying to do:

```
-python process captures stderr of multiple subprocesses to watch the subprocesses
-each subprocess runs on the separate window displaying stdout.
```

When I use **Popen(*command*,stderr = *fp4tempfile*)**,

```
(good) the python process can capture stderr of the subprocesses
(bad ) the subprocess shells stop displaying stdout.
```

When I use **Popen(*command*)**,

```
(good) each subprocess shells displays stdout (as well as stderr, which does not matter for me), 
(bad ) the python process cannot capture stderr.
```

I want both "good"s. What can I do for this? Thanks in advance.
(currently, I'm using python3.2 developing in windows7)

Here's the parent process source written in python:

```
import os,subprocess
import time
fpws = []
fprs = []

def run_command(command):
    <specifying a file to write -- skipped>
    fpw = open(ftempname,'w')
    fpr = open(ftempname,'r')
    #cmd_redirect = "%s 2>%s" % (command,ftempname)#didnt do anything
    #starting a sub-program:
    pp = subprocess.Popen(command,stderr = fpw) #++
    #pp = subprocess.Popen(command)             #@@
    fpws.append(fpw)
    fprs.append(fpr)    

def watch_program():
    while True: #running forever for simplfication
        for fpr in  fprs:
            outchunk = fpr.read()
            <do something for subprocesses stderr -- skipped>
            time.sleep(1.0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmd1 = '(path to program1)'
    cmd2 = '(path to program2)'
    run_command(cmd1)  #kicking cmd1
    run_command(cmd2)  #kicking cmd2
    watch_program()          #hearing stderr msg from the other process
```

Note: in the subprocess side, fflush(stdout) and  fflush(stderr) are called as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but can you do

```
import sys

pp = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr = fpw, stdout = sys.stdout)
```

Comment: Edit: didn't notice that the subprocesses are in different windows.  Not sure why changing the stderr has any effect on what's being output to stdout.  Are you sure that the reason the output's going away is that it's actually stderr?

Answer (score 0):

I82Much, thank you for your answer and comment.

Yes, your comment about stderr was absolutely right. I was developing in windows7. In linux (ubuntu10), the following simply worked out:

```
    cmd_line4sub = command + ' 2> ' + ftempname
    pp = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/xterm','-e',cmd_line4sub],stderr = fpw)
```

It opens new shells, printing subprocess stdout. The parent process captures subprocess stderr. It is my first goal.

If I could ever figure out how to do in windows, I'll post my answer;)

(I'm the same user as the questioner, but I cannot make them the same account...)